# Thoughts about objc runtime

Tags: objective-c

Correct me if I'm wrong in my logic.

In java we can call methods like this

```
Object.doSomething(); // here we call method directly
```

In objc we do

```
[object doSomething];
```

Here doSomething message is sent to object. As I know every object have isa pointer which points to the object class. Objc runtime use that pointer to check if object class have such a method If no it check it's parent and so on. If a method is found objc_msgSend is called.

Here I am confused.

What is a difference between method calls in Java and messages in Objc ?

What are advantage / disadvantage between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message routing is done at runtime (objc) - method binding at compile time (java). The objc runtime resolves the method at runtime and may find something in the class/superclass, forward it to some other object (forwardInvocation) or fail (method not found). Thats why objc ppl talk about messages (dynamic) and java ppl talk about methods (static). The advantage is more dynamic behavior the disadvantage the possible runtime error.

Comment: Java method calling is actually not bound at compile time. Reflection and other things can change what happens on a method call, so this answer is actually invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused on how `objc_msgSend` works, `objc_msgSend` is itself what sends the message, there isn't a check to see if the class contains the method first. That is handled by the sending framework. This allows messages to be rerouted by classes at runtime like `NSProxy`.